# We write down the date of each person's birthday we meet (say Feb 29. doesn't exist).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

Random Variable $X$ is the number on persons we met til we wrote down every date in a year. Find the expected value of $X$. Find $E(X)$- expected value.

From this example I can definitely understand the true nature of expected value. How do I do this? This is what I tried:

Every date $x_i$ in a year has a $P(x_i)= \frac{1}{365}$on meeting the next person, that's the only useful information I can muster up, and I don't know how to use it. I feel like this is not a easy example.. Any help is well received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

The expected value is

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = N H_N \approx N \, ln \, N$$

where $H_N$ is $N$-th harmonic number.

Here $\mathbb{E}(X) \approx 2364.64$

The idea in solving this problem is calculating the expected number of people such that the number of different birthdays we have written increases from $n$ to $n+1$.

Comment: This probably is there answer, but I just don't see how $t_i$ is a geometric distribution in the calculation of expectation ?

Comment: Suppose you have registered $n$ different dates and want to know after how many people you will increase the number of dates to $n+1$. You ask $t_i$ person its birthday date: if it's in the list you continue asking; if it isn't then you have $n+1$ different dates. The geometric distribution counts the number of people you have to ask until you have success (getting $n+1$ dates) given the probabilities.

Comment: Each time you've found a unique date you start a new search. If you've found $n$ unique dates so far, then the probability of finding the $n+1$ unique birthday is $(365-n)/365)$, and the number people you have to talk to in order to find that unique birthday is geometrically distributed.

Comment: @Blex, shouldn't it be $NlnN$ ?

Comment: It does. I assume $log(N)$ is natural logarithm, $ln(N)$ notation is better.

Comment: I'm afraid I've muddled things up here. $E(X)≈2364.64$ is correct, but that's approximately $365(.577+ln(365))$ while $365ln(365)≈2153.46$ Best if I ignore any desire to post before coffee.